# Ejecutar código php sin tener que abrir página web

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, stripe

Tengo una página web en la cual se pueden hacer pagos con tarjetas de crédito/débito y por oxxo, lo que quiero saber es como haría para tener ejecutando un código php que estaría verificando el estado de los pagos por oxxo.

No necesariamente tengo que tener la página abierta, por que se supone que automáticamente ese código debe estar verificando el estado de los pagos que se vayan a pagar por oxxo y hacer la modificación en la base de datos.

Estoy usando la api de stripe para poder hacer este tipo de pago.

```
<?php
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_APIKEY');

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentIntent
        handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);
        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentMethod
        handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}

http_response_code(200);
?>
```

Ese es el código php que tengo que ejecutar, viene en la documentación de **stripe** [Triggering actions with webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events#build-your-own-webhook)

La verdad no le entiendo nada, ojala que me pudieran orientar como hacer eso?

Comment: Agrega un script de PHP al crontab

Comment: Si lo que quieres es iniciar algo desde Javascript y que se continue ejecutando aunque se cierre la página: [Manejo de Conexiones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.connection-handling.php)

Comment: Agrega un cron, no inventes el hilo negro.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar con Cron Jobs si tu servidor es linux y le definirias el tiempo que se ejecute y el script php mas o menos asi:

```
php -q /home/tuUsuarioCpanel/public_html/archivo.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un endpoint el cual al ser llamado ejecute ese código. Stripe hace un request POST en ese endpoint por cada webhook que se envía. La dirección la puedes especificar en https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks

Este es el flujo de un webhook:

```
 --------                      -------------
| Stripe | - POST /webhook -> | Tu servidor | -> Ejecuta el código de ejemplo.
 --------                      -------------
```

Comment: El archivo que va a contener el código que stripe pone de ejemplo, no tengo que mandar a ejecutarlo?? Stripe lo ejecutará?? No tengo que ejecutar comandos en consola??

Comment: No tienes que mandar a ejecutarlo. Stripe hace un llamado HTTP al Endpoint que configures en el Stripe Dashboard. Al hacer esa llamada, se ejecuta el código que tengas en ese Endpoint.